# Is there a closed form of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(4n+1)!!}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, factorial

This may be an impossible problem.  But I imagine it's worth asking still.
What is the closed form of the sum:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(4n+1)!!}$$

Perhaps there isn't a closed form.  Double factorials are WAY out of my comfort zone so any tips would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^n \over \pars{4n + 1}!!}}  =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^n \over \prod_{k = 0}^{2n}\pars{2k + 1}} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^n \over
2^{2n + 1}\prod_{k = 0}^{2n}\pars{k + 1/2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^n \over
2^{2n + 1}\pars{1/2}^{\overline{2n + 1}}} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^n \over
2^{2n + 1}\bracks{\Gamma\pars{2n + 3/2}/\Gamma\pars{1/2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^n \over 2^{2n + 1}}\,{1 \over \pars{2n}!}\,
{\Gamma\pars{2n + 1}\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{2n + 3/2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1/4}^n \over \pars{2n}!}\,
\int_{0}^{1}t^{2n}\pars{1 - t}^{-1/2}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-t^{2}/4}^n \over \pars{2n}!}}\pars{1 - t}^{-1/2}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}
\bracks{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{\ic t/2}^{2n} \over \pars{2n}!}}
\pars{1 - t}^{-1/2}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}
\bracks{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{\ic t/2}^{n} \over n!}\,{1 + \pars{-1}^{n} \over 2}}
\pars{1 - t}^{-1/2}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}
\bracks{\Re\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{\ic t/2}^{n} \over n!}}
\pars{1 - t}^{-1/2}\,\dd t =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\cos\pars{t/2} \over \root{1 - t}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\root{\pi}\bracks{\mrm{C}\pars{1 \over \root{\pi}}\cos\pars{1 \over 2} +
\mrm{S}\pars{1 \over \root{\pi}}\sin\pars{1 \over 2}}}
\\[5mm] & \approx 0.9344
\end{align}

$\ds{\mrm{C}\ \mbox{and}\ \mrm{S}}$ are
[FresnelC Function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FresnelC.html)
and [FresnelS Function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FresnelS.html), respectively.

In the last integral, the change
$\ds{\pars{\root{1 - t} = x \implies t = 1 - x^{2}}}$ yields inmediately the final solution.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment:

This series converges by the Ratio Test.

I am not going to pretend to know much about the "[generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function)". But if you just need the answer and not the derivation, then [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20n%3D0%20to%20infinity%20of%20%28-1%29%5En%20%2F%20%284n%2B1%29%21%21) produces this output as well as using the [Fresnel C and S integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(4n+1)!!}  =  \ _1F_2 \left( 1; \frac{3}{4}; \frac{5}{4}; \frac{-1}{16}   \right) \\ = \sqrt{\pi} \ \ C \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \right) \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) + \sqrt{\pi} \ \ S \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \right) \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)$$

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment.*

Using the same approach as in @Xoque55's answer, we could go one step further and consider
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(4n+1)!!}x^{4n}=\, _1F_2\left(1;\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};-\frac{x^4}{16}\right)$$ which write
$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt \pi}x \left(C\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)+S\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right) \sin
   \left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right) \right)$$